# Displaying emojis in powerBI via SQL

Tags: powerbi

I am using an Azure logic App to capture tweets into an SQL database.  In the database and in PowerBI I can see black and white renditions of the emojis.  However, in Power BI they just show as question marks?  Any ideas how I can fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the unicode number that represents the character you can pass those values to the [UNICHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/unichar-function-dax) dax function. Assuming you are working with AS 2016 or greater the emojis will render.

Comment: Yes but that only works for the emoji character on it own.  Bear in mind that the emoji is in a text sentence/phrase and should still be shown within it's context.  Therefore this is not a solution unfortunately.

Comment: How are you planning on displaying/visualizing the data? If you need to display the emoji in the field itself (in a table) I don't think you will have any luck. If you are trying to display these sentences/phrases in a visual then just use some text functions to separate before and after the unicode and then concatenate once everything is formatted.

Comment: Yes it's in a table.  I have seen it done in the Microsoft Campaign management template for Twitter and PowerBI so it is possible just not sure how!

Comment: In the table in your model itself or in a table visual? can you post some pics of what you are seeing? And perhaps what you'd like to see?

Comment: It's just standard table from PowerBI and I want to show emojis.  I found this elsewhere: ="data:image/png;base64," &[column storing the pic].   This then shows the emoji but then I am stuck with "data:image/png;base64," in front of every tweet